# Docker error & Lagom conduct visualization

Tags: docker, sbt, hyper-v, typesafe, lagom

I have seen in some Lightben tutorials they are using ***TypeSafe conductr*** to visualize the services and api, but no one has explained how to prepare it to run conduct from command prompt. in [ConductR CLI](http://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/1.1.x/CLI) it is explained some vague instruction dependent on Docker. but my docker faces this error: (windows10)

```
Unable to start: The VM couldn't get an IP address after 60 tries
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 340
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
```

my first problem is how to resolve the HyperV problem here and does any one know a clear approach for typesafe conductr ?

Answer (score 1):

To run ConductR locally, you should follow the instructions for the [ConductR Developer Sandbox](https://www.lightbend.com/product/conductr/developer).
Please note that to access that page, you need to [sign up for a free Lightbend developer account](https://www.lightbend.com/account/register), as ConductR is commercial software and you need to accept some terms and conditions.
For alternatives to ConductR to deploy Lagom applications, see [Deploying to Other Platforms](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.1.x/java/Overview.html#deploying-to-other-platforms).

Comment: Thanks, I used the approach explained in sandbox, not the previous errors but 10s of new errors :)

Comment: Sorry to hear you have new errors. Maybe create a new Stackoverflow question for them?